# Google Analytics tracking over multiple tabs

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I want to know if GA4 can track multiple tabs to one user, the reason is we have a site and a tool combined into one, the tool or site requires opening a new tab.

Comment: this question is off topic, so it will probably be closed . But the answer is YES